# Looking to insert div into html body with xsl 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Pretty simple: What I'm looking for a simple XSL to change

```
    <body>
      ...
    </body>
```

To

```
    <body>
      ...
      <div>...</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're much more likely to get good responses here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work can give the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
      <xsl:template match="body">
           <xsl:apply-templates />
           <div>...</div>
      </xsl:template>   
      <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:variable name="curTagName" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$curTagName}">
                <!-- Walk through the attributes -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
                    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*">
            <xsl:variable name="curAttName" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="{$curAttName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>
```